# Compling my VB.NET WinForms apps for ARM and Windows RT

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, arm

Now that [Windows RT has been jailbroken](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092158) I want to port my VB app to Windows RT. How do I compile my VB.NET WinForms app for ARM? It it possible to do it within VS Express? I have "VS Express for Windows 8" and "VS Express for Desktop". My app uses no custom libraries or controls so it shouldn't be a problem, as long as it possible to compile it for ARM. Is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the build output from your app as-is. One important factor to keep in mind, any P/Invokes or dependencies on Unmanaged code will most likely *not* work on Windows RT without also porting these unmanaged libraries. As long as your project is AnyCPU, it should just work.

The CLR (Common Language Runtime) will do the actual JIT (Just In Time) compilation to the ARM processor instructions for you. No recompilation needed.

Comment: That's great news! I don't have a Windows RT device to test on. Is there some sort of developer VM?

Comment: Nope. Developer VM is a normal Windows 8 machine. Since you're not able to use these API's under normal circumstances. Microsoft has no need to provide a VM under which you can do desktop development on a Windows RT device. And ModernUI apps can be deployed and tested ona regular Windows 8 machine just fine (same API, same limitations).

Comment: Thank you! I had to build the app with VS Express for Desktops 2012 with .NET Framework 4.5 (the previous version had been built with VB 2010 and .Net Framework 4 Client Profile) but it runs! I had a person on the XDA forums test it and it runs. Thank you for your advice.